# Как увеличить результаты поиска по своим объектам в Yandex Api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Организовал поиск по своим объектам через ObjectManager по примеру в [песочнице](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search). Вне зависимости от количества найденных результатов всегда выводит в окне поиска только 10. Как увеличить их количество хотя бы до 20?